# Шифрование сообщения матричным методом

Tags: c++, алгоритм, файлы, указатели

Мне нужно было написать код для матричного метода шифрования сообщения из файла. Проверил, вроде бы ошибок и нету. Но все же пишет "undefined symbol 'f1'" Я же ведь правильно создал указатель на файл? Почему тогда выбивает ошибку?

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<iostream.h>

void main()
{
     int i=0,j=0,count=0,c;
     char l,sim[20];
     FILE *fl;
     if ((f1=fopen("D:\\11.txt","r"))==NULL)
     {
      printf("Error! Cannot open file");
      getch();
      return 0;
     }
     while( fscanf(f1,"%c",&l) == 1 )
     {
      sim[i]=l;
      printf("%c", sim[i]);
      i++;
      count++;
     }
     c=count;
     printf("\n Text dla shufruvana:\n\n");
     printf(" ");
     for(count=0;count<c;count++)
     {
      printf("%c",sim[count]);
     }
     printf("\n");
     fclose(fl);
     printf("\n Text y vugljadi chisel");
     for(count=0;count<c;count++)
     {
      if(sim[count]=='a'){sim[count]=1;}
      if(sim[count]=='b'){sim[count]=2;}
      if(sim[count]=='c'){sim[count]=3;}
      if(sim[count]=='d'){sim[count]=4;}
      if(sim[count]=='e'){sim[count]=5;}
      if(sim[count]=='f'){sim[count]=6;}
      if(sim[count]=='g'){sim[count]=7;}
      if(sim[count]=='h'){sim[count]=8;}
      if(sim[count]=='i'){sim[count]=9;}
      if(sim[count]=='j'){sim[count]=10;}
      if(sim[count]=='k'){sim[count]=11;}
      if(sim[count]=='l'){sim[count]=12;}
      if(sim[count]=='m'){sim[count]=13;}
      if(sim[count]=='n'){sim[count]=14;}
      if(sim[count]=='o'){sim[count]=15;}
      if(sim[count]=='p'){sim[count]=16;}
      if(sim[count]=='q'){sim[count]=17;}
      if(sim[count]=='r'){sim[count]=18;}
      if(sim[count]=='s'){sim[count]=19;}
      if(sim[count]=='t'){sim[count]=20;}
      if(sim[count]=='u'){sim[count]=21;}
      if(sim[count]=='v'){sim[count]=22;}
      if(sim[count]=='w'){sim[count]=23;}
      if(sim[count]=='x'){sim[count]=24;}
      if(sim[count]=='y'){sim[count]=25;}
      if(sim[count]=='z'){sim[count]=26;}
      if(sim[count]==' '){sim[count]=27;}
      printf("%3d",sim[count]);
     }
      printf("\n Kilkst sumvoliv : %d\n",count);

      int m,n,a[50][50],shifr[50][50],key[2][2];
      printf("\n\n Vvedit kilkist rjadkiv m=");
      scanf("%d",&m);
      printf(" Vedit vvedit kilkist stovpciv n=");
      scanf("%d",&n);
      printf("\n");
      for(i=1;i<m+1;i++)
      {
       printf("\n");
       for(j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
        count=n*(i-1)+j;
        a[i][j]=sim[count];
        printf (" %d",a[i][j],",");
       }
      }
       getch();
       clrscr();

       printf("\n\n\n Vvedit matricu kluchiv %d na %d",m,n);
       for(i=0;i<m;i++)
       {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
         printf(" key[%d][%d]=",i,j);
         scanf("%d",&key[i][j]);
        }
       }
       int p=0;
       getch();
       clrscr();
       printf("\n");
       for(i=1;i<m+1;i++)
       {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
         shifr[i][j]=0;
         for(p=0;p<n;p++)
         {
          shifr[i][j]+=a[i][p]*key[p][j];
         }
        }
       }
       printf("\n");
       printf("\n Shifr:\n");
       for(i=1;i<m+1;i++)
       {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
         printf("%12d",shifr[i][j]);
        }
       }
       getch();
       f2=fopen("D:\\SHIFR.txt","w");
       for(i=1;i<m+1;i++)
       {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
         fprintf(fl,"%6d",shifr[i][j]);
        }
       }
       fclose(f2);
       printf("\n");
       getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас имеется опечатка. В этом предложении

```
FILE *fl;
```

вы используете латинскую букву `'l'` вместо единицы.

Обратите внимание, что функция `main` должна иметь тип возвращаемого значения `int`:

```
int main()
```

Также заголовки указаны неверно. Например, должно быть

```
#include <iostream>
```

вместо

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

если только вы не используете какой-нибудь очень древний C++ компилятор. И вам необходимо включить заголовок

```
#include <cstdio>
```

если программа пишется на C++ или

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

если программа пишется на C.

В этом цикле

```
 while( fscanf(f1,"%c",&l) == 1 )
 {
  sim[i]=l;
  printf("%c", sim[i]);
  i++;
  count++;
 }
```

вы обязаны проверять, что не выйдете за границу массива `sim`. Поэтому он должен выглядеть по крайней мере как

```
 while( i < sizeof( sim ) && fscanf(f1,"%c",&l) == 1 )
 {
  sim[i]=l;
  printf("%c", sim[i]);
  i++;
  count++;
 }
```

И в целом это очень плохая идея использовать средства ввода-вывода языка C  в программе, которая, возвожно, написана на C++.:)

Вообще-то, ваш вопрос должен быть перенесен в раздел языка программирования C. В вашей программе нет ничего от C++ кроме неправильного заголовка `<iostream.h>`.:)

Comment: Программа писалась в Builder C++)

Comment: а почему функция main должна иметь тип возвращаемого значения?

Comment: @Muscled Boy  Согласно стандартам языков C и C++ функция main должна иметь тип возвращаемого значения int.

Comment: ясно, спасибо,  учту  на будущее